# ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and multiclass targets (XGBoost)

Tags: python, xgboost, xgbclassifier

for a project I'm using a classifier, with XGBoost. Here is a part of the code:

```
import ...

tab = 'tab.csv'
datasset = read_csv(tab, decimal=".")

target_attribute = dataset['AVG']

a = random.randrange(1, 1000)
seed = a
test_size = 0.33
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset, target_attribute, test_size=test_size,
                                                        random_state=seed)

X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_train = X_train.astype(float)
X_test = X_test.astype(float)

model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(model)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)

print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

As soon as I use a certain target_attribute I get the following error:

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and multiclass targets

I'm using classification, so my internet search so far didn't really help solving this problem. I *think* that the problem might be in the fact that in this column in the .csv the values are both integer and real numbers. I've no idea how to solve this problem. I hope that somebody here can help me.

**EDIT:** I already tried to force all columns with dtype == 'int64' to be the dtype == 'float64'. This sadly didn't help.

Comment: what is the dtype of target_attribute?

Comment: It's int64 - I tried forcing the dtpye being float64, but I got the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error earlier and I know it is an old question but if anyone faces this issue, it may be because of `model.predict`.
So what you need to do is change the code a little, like shown below:

```
pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test), axis=1)
print(accuracy_score(labels, pred))
```

`pred` will store the class with maximum probability and finally you use `accuracy_score` to print the accuracy.

I hope this help :)